# What event can I use when the audio suspended because of insufficient loaded data (slow speeds)?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What event can I use when the audio suspended because of insufficient loaded data (slow speeds) ?

Just like:

```
$audio.on('suspendToLoading',function(){
    alert('loading...');
});
```

And I had try to use `suspend waiting abort load loading`. None of them can be work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `stalled` event, however, it is sometimes known to not trigger even if the loading actually has stalled.

> The user agent is trying to fetch media data, but data is unexpectedly
>   not forthcoming.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio#Media_Events)

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796420/how-to-identify-that-html5-media-element-is-stalled-and-waiting-for-further-medi/29803523#29803523) for a possible workaround when stalled does not trigger.